# Solving $x^4 -10x^3 + 26x^2 -10x +1 = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the root of the  equation 
$$x^4 -10x^3 + 26x^2 -10x +1 = 0$$

**My attempt:**

If $a,b,c$ and $d$ are a roots then $a+b+c+d = 10,$

$(a+b)(c+d)  + ab +cd = 26$

$(a+b)cd  +ab(c+d) = 10$

$abcd =1$

Now  i'm not able  procceed further.

Comment: You can ask Wolfy.

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E4%E2%88%9210x%5E3%2B26x%5E2%E2%88%9210x%2B1%3D0) gives the answers

Comment: the $\alpha\beta\gamma$ method allows you to transform roots or sometimes find them if you know information about them relative to each other, but since you don't have this you cannot solve $f(x)$ using this method. For anything above cubics numerical methods always work well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

.For palindromic polynomials (whose coefficients read the same from left to right), it is key to realize that for $x \neq 0$, we have $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $f(\frac 1x) = 0$. This is a routine check which I leave to you.

More precisely, note that $x = 0$ is not a root of the polynomial above. Therefore, dividing by $x^2$ and collecting terms, we have :
$$
x^2 + \frac 1{x^2} - 10\left(x + \frac 1x\right) + 26 = 0
$$

Note that $x^2 + \frac 1{x^2} = \left(x + \frac 1x\right)^2 - 2$. Therefore, setting $x + \frac 1x = y$, we get a quadratic polynomial in $y$, which can be solved to get two values of $y$, followed by four values of $x$.

---

More precisely, $y^2 -10y + 24 = 0$.  So we get $y  = 4,6$ so $x + \frac 1x = 4$ or $x + \frac 1x  = 6$. Solve these to get $2 \pm \sqrt 3$ and $3 \pm 2 \sqrt 2$. Either from here, or from the earlier equations you may notice that they come in pairs whose product is $1$.

Comment: thanks u  @actoh

Comment: You are welcome! Note that the formula for the roots of a quartic equation are so complicated that you will not be required to remember them for any exam or olympiad. Therefore, knowing tricks like this will help you get around quartic equations which are presented as "simply solved" or "reduced to quadratic".

Answer (score 7):

You can proceede also like this:

\begin{eqnarray}x^4 -10x^3 + 26x^2 -10x +1 &=& (x^4 -4x^3 + 6x^2 -4x +1)-6x(x^2-2x+1)+8x^2\\
&=& (x-1)^4-6x(x-1)^2+8x^2\\
&=& \Big((x-1)^2-4x\Big)\Big((x-1)^2-2x\Big)\\
&=& \Big(x^2-6x+1\Big)\Big(x^2-4x+1\Big)\\
\end{eqnarray}